# I need a .bat file to select mutiple files and run a perl script

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file

Basically I want to pass multiple input files as arguments and run my perl script. I already have a .bat script which selects a single file. Is there anyway to have .bat file which gives an option to select multiple files using the ctrl key just the way we have that option when we attach files to say an email.

Help would be greatly appreciated...
Thanks!!!!

Existing .bat script

[image]

Comment: What does your `.bat` script look like?

Comment: Please make your question more clear. Add example and what you have tried.

Comment: Have added the image of the .bat file in the description.

Comment: still your question is not very clear. I think basically you want to process multiple files using .bat script.

Comment: Never post images of code. Post actual code. But using cmd to generate vbscript to generate HTML... why do this to yourself? Do it all in perl, or PowerShell, or pretty much anything else.

Comment: For Example i want to run my perl script this way "perl run.pl file1.log file2.log file3.log" I just want to be able to select these files in one go and run the script using the .bat file.

Comment: how you will process those arguments in your bat script?.will you call your bat script from perl script using system command

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me. I believe you want to process your command line arguments using perl.

Run code :

```
perl run.pl file1.log file2.log file3.log
```

code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $val1= $ARGV[0];
my $val2 = $ARGV[1];
my $val3 = $ARGV[2];
print "$val1\n$val2\n$val3\n";
```

output

```
file1.log 
file2.log 
file3.log
```

In this way you can get arguments in the perl script then you can process them.

Hope this will help you .

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to allow the user to select files, you don't need the dance with a `.bat` script that writes a `.vbs` script that writes a `.hta` script that writes the result to the registry.

You can do it directly in Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::GUI ();

my @files = Win32::GUI::GetOpenFileName(
    -filemustexist => 1,
    -multisel      => 1,
);

if (@files == 1 && !defined $files[0]) {
    print "Canceled\n";
} elsif (@files == 1) {
    print "Selected one file: $files[0]\n";
} else {
    my $dir = shift @files;
    print "Selected multiple files in $dir\n";
    for my $file (@files) {
        print " - $file\n";
    }
}
```

If you don't have Win32::GUI yet (`Can't locate Win32/GUI.pm in @INC ...`), you can install it using `cpan Win32::GUI`, at least with [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/). If you're using [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl), I think you can get it with `ppm install Win32-GUI`.